# Derive functions with interface - F#

Tags: interface, f#, calculator

I'm new to F# and I'm trying to implement a little calculator with these interfaces...
But I'm struggling with the derive part as soon as i get to f_add.
Would be nice if someone could help me out. :)

```
type IFunction =
    interface
        abstract member ToString: Unit -> String
        abstract member Apply: Nat -> Nat
        abstract member Derive: Unit -> IFunction
    end
```

Comment: I tried to address your _specific_ issue, but I'd also recommend asking on the F# forums or fsharporg slack for some code review help - there's quite a bit here that could be written in more "typical F#" style, too, which might be worth exploring as you continue to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `f_add` is defined in curried form (typical for F# functions), and not tupled, you need to pass the arguments with spaces, not as a tuple:

```
//                                     HERE .  Using comma makes that a tuple
// member self.Derive () = f_add(f.Derive (), g.Derive ()) //wrong
```

Instead, pass as an F# style function:

```
member self.Derive () = f_add (f.Derive ()) (g.Derive ())
```

The same issue exists in the other implementations.

Comment: I knew it was easy to fix but just couldnt see it :D Thanks a lot for helping out, now everything works fine :)

Comment: Glad you have it resolved, @Guna but in the future please consider posting an actual error message rather than //wrong. The error codes and messages usually help to understand better what is the issue as well as allow for the search engines to find these questions in the future.